# Bind fields from nested objects Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

We have to bind from a regular form made with Thymeleaf. We have a parent object with a nested object with some fields.

We have put a select element like this :

```html
<select name="cumplirCiaps"  th:onchange="|onChangueCumplirEpisodios(this);|">
    <option th:each="condicionEpisodios : ${radioCumplirTodosEpisodios}"
                th:text="${condicionEpisodios.descripcion}"
                th:value="${condicionEpisodios.codigo}"
                th:selected="${condicionEpisodios.codigo}"
                th:disabled="${modoConsulta != null}"
                th:field="${consultaCias.consultaExplotacionCupos.cumplirCiaps}" />
</select>
```

We have to bind the value from the element we select in `cumplirCiaps` in the field from nested object. I put `th:field="${consultaCias.consultaExplotacionCupos.cumplirCiaps}"` but when post this form and get value inside the method , we got null value. Anybody know solve this problem from the field in nested objects?

Answer (score 0):

you should set `th:field` for `select` not for `option`